# How to change airbyte normalization images

Tags: devops, airbyte

I have airbyet chart running in my own cluster. I changed the name of the docker images of all containers running in Airbyte to the same as in my own repo. However, the container created while normalizing still uses the default airbyte/normalization:0.4.3 image. How can I change this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say here https://docs.airbyte.com/using-airbyte/core-concepts/basic-normalization#airbyte-integrationbasesbase-normalization

> Note that Basic Normalization is packaged in a docker image airbyte/normalization. This image is tied to and released along with a specific Airbyte version. It is not configurable independently like it is possible to do with connectors (source & destinations)
>
> Therefore, in order to "upgrade" to the desired normalization version, you need to use the corresponding Airbyte version that it's being released in

Perhaps one of the pull requests listed there can give you clues as to the remaining changes you need to make to your airbyte fork.